# Why my ArrayList declaration fails?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
package collections;
import java.util.*;  

public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();  
          al.


    }

}
```

I am not able to create the array list of generic type. I am getting an error indicating that :

> The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments`<String>`

I have my jdk version above 1.5 (ie 1.8). Can anyone clarify the issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your Classname is same as Classname in java.util **ArrayList**, When you create object of type ArrayList it cannot find Proper class. 
This is not Java 1.5/1.8 issue.

Remember do not name your classes as ArrayList, Map or any other such java.util ClassNames.

Solution is to rename your classname, rename your filename to the same classname as it contains main() method.

Below code should work, save it as **ArrayListTry.java**

```
public class ArrayListTry {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();  
      //al.
      }
}
```

Comment: ArrayList is not a keyword. Nor is Map. It's just a class name in another package. You can still call your own class ArrayList if you must, and then your code will compile if you use `java.util.ArrayList<String> al = new java.util.ArrayList<>();` (but that's not recommended).

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes, I have reframed the sentences of the answer, Thank you for pointing out.